# Pass parameters to the login view in a jetsream project

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I'm just getting started with Laravel and I'm using jetstream on a project for authentication.

I want to modify the login page and **replace the email field with a select tag having the names of the registered users as options** so that they will just have to choose their name in the list and enter their password to log in.
My problem is that I don't know how to **make the data (from Users table) available when arriving on login page**.

I've found the related route file `vendor\laravel\fortify\routes\routes.php` and got the following code inside :

```
// Authentication...
if ($enableViews) {
    Route::get('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
        ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')])
        ->name('login');
}
```

Then I found `AuthenticatedSessionController.php` in `vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Http\Controllers` in order to modify the `create` function so that I could send the data through it, but here's actually the function :

```
public function create(Request $request): LoginViewResponse
{
    return app(LoginViewResponse::class);
}
```

It doesn't return a view - in which case I think everything would have been fine - and I don't know how to handle this.

```
// vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Contracts\LoginViewResponse.php

namespace Laravel\Fortify\Contracts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Responsable;

interface LoginViewResponse extends Responsable
{
    //
}
```

Comment: You can check this tutorial I think it can help https://youtu.be/NiQSNjWKLfU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FortifyServiceProvider.php you can bind the data to the view like :

```
Fortify::loginView(function () {
   $users = User::all();
   return view('auth.login',compact('users'));
});
```